# Is atmospheric pressure linearly dependent on atmospheric temperature?

Tags: pressure, temperature, atmospheric-science

Is it true that atmospheric pressure is linearly dependent on atmospheric temperature?

Answer (score 2):

No. The atmosphere is thin enough that the variation of gravity from bottom to top is a small correction on top of larger sources of variation. Atmospheric pressure at a point can be regarded as due to the weight of the air stacked on top of that point, and though the air expands with increasing temperature, its weight doesn’t change.

If temperature increases in a column of air and surrounding areas don’t warm as well, some of the air mass from the warm column will be expelled, decreasing the pressure at the base of the column.